# Undefined Symbols with Python.h

Tags: c++, python, python-2.7

I'm trying to embed a Python script into a C++ application. Before I do such a thing though, I'm trying to run the example script.

Here's my code:

```
#include <Python/Python.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                   "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

Compiling with g++ gives me:

```
Undefined symbols:
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      _main in cc2Ogphq.o
  "_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags", referenced from:
      _main in cc2Ogphq.o
  "_Py_Finalize", referenced from:
      _main in cc2Ogphq.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
```

I'm running Mac OSX Snow Leopard and I'm running Python 2.7.2.

Comment: What command did you use to compile ? Did you include the python library in the linker options ?

Comment: I just did "g++ main.cpp". I gather that this isn't the right way to do it. As you can probably tell I don't program in C++ much...

Comment: You'll need to link to the python library to get its symbols. Check the version of the python library you have installed, and then link to that by adding `-lpython2.6` to the compilation command eg. (refer to the answer already given below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link to the python libraries, e.g. `libpython.a` for static linkage.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is old and yucky (static, eww).

[distutils](http://docs.python.org/extending/building.html#building) is the answer for most cases.

If you really insist on DIY, add this to your ~/.profile:

```
# Works on Lion

alias pygcc='gcc -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/ /usr/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib'

alias pyg++='gcc -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/ /usr/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.dylib'
```

Usage:
   pyg++ yourfile.cc

pygcc someotherfile.c

Answer (score 0):

of course, i'm some late with my answer ,
   but i had a identical problem  and i was needed 
  to do some searches 
 i use ubuntu 11, bash shell
 solve is:

g++ c_pyth.cpp -o c_pyth   -I /usr/include/python2.7/   /usr/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.so

if you don't include /usr/include/python2.7/   ,compiler won't see   "Python.h"

if you don't include  /usr/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.so , compiler won't be able to make static executable file